# How to pass multiple necessary patterns to str_subset?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to find elements in a character vector that match two words in no particular order, not just any single one of them, using the stringr::str_subset function. In other words, I'm looking for the intersection, not the union of the two words.

I tried using the "or" (|) operator but this only gives me either one of the two words and returns too many results. I also tried just passing a character vector with the two words as the pattern argument. This just returns the error that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" and only returns the values that match the second one of the two words.

```
character_vector <- c("abc ghi jkl mno def", "pqr abc def", "abc jkl pqr")
pattern <- c("def", "pqr")

str_subset(character_vector, pattern)
```

I'm looking for the pattern that will return only the second element of the character vector, i.e. "pqr abc def".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is `str_detect`.  Loop over the 'pattern', check if both the 'pattern' elements match with the 'character_vector' (`&`), use the logical vector to `extract` the element from the 'character_vector'

```
library(tidyverse)
map(pattern, str_detect, string = character_vector) %>%
    reduce(`&`) %>% 
    magrittr::extract(character_vector, .)
#[1] "pqr abc def"
```

---

Or using `str_subset`

```
map(pattern, str_subset, string = character_vector) %>% 
         reduce(intersect)
#[1] "pqr abc def"
```

Comment: The second solution is really elegant. This is the one I used. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you are looking for the intersect, you can use the function `intersect()` and explicit the 2 patterns you are looking for

`pattern_1 <- 'pqr'`

`pattern_2 <- 'def'`

`intersect(
   str_subset(character_vector, pattern_1), 
   str_subset(character_vector, pattern_2)
)`

Comment: I like the simplicity! Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer and to give an up vote to all useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pure R code with out a loop using regular expression. The code is like this:

```
character_vector[grepl(paste0("(?=.*",pattern,")",collapse = ""), character_vector, perl = TRUE)]
```

the `grepl` would find the position of the character that full fills the regex and condition inside the paste0.

Comment: Interesting! What does the perl argument do here?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
character_vector %>% purrr::reduce(pattern, str_subset, .init = . )

[1] "pqr abc def"
```